# Returns all rows which have same column value based on other column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I have the following table:

```
Id      | sid          | email
___________________________________________________
1       | 10           | john@yahoo.com
2       | 11           | elsa@gmail.com
3       | 10           | johnconnor@gmail.com
4       | 10           | john.smith@gmail.com
5       | 12           | ninjamutant@yahoo.com
```

I would like to query all rows which have same "sid" by passing known "email"
So if I pass the email as "john.smith@gmail.com", it should return rows with id number 1, 3, and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
select * from yourtable a
inner join (
    select sid 
    from yourtable
    where email = "john.smith@gmail.com"
) b on b.sid = a.sid
```

Comment: Excellent...! Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

```
select T2.*
from my_table T1 join my_table T2
on T1.sid = T2.sid
where T1.email = 'xxx'
```

Comment: A bit dangerous. (sub-select returns more that 1 row may occur, depending on table data.)

Comment: replace `=` with `IN`.

Comment: `select top 1` is for sql server. use `limit 1` for mysql.